# The extension SearchPanes does not exist

Tags: r, datatable, markdown, dt

I try to use the extension searchPanes of the library DT with R.
I use the code from this source :  https://rstudio.github.io/DT/extensions.html

```
library(DT)
datatable(
  iris,
  options = list(dom = 'Pfrtip', columnDefs = list(list(
    searchPanes = list(show = FALSE), targets = 1:4
  ))),
  extensions = c('Select', 'SearchPanes'),
  selection = 'none'
)
```

I get this error:

> Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : The extension SearchPanes does not exist

I don't understand how to make this code works.

Thanks!

Comment: works fine for me. Perhaps update your packages.